# Add a class to main menu links

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I've searched and found variations of this question but I've never found an answer that seemed to work. I need to add a class to the `<li>` elements, currently the main menu is rendered like this:

```php
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $main_menu,
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'slidemenu',
        'class' => array(
            'links',
            'inline',
            'clearfix'
        )
    ),
    'heading' => t('')
));
```

As far as I can tell, this only sets up the `<ul>` element of the main menu, so I was wondering if there's a way to edit the attributes of the `'links'` part.

---EDIT---

Alright, I think I solved it. Apparently you can use `theme_links__system_main_menu` in templates to override the whole thing. I ended up doing this:

```php
function mytheme_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
    $html = '<div id="mainmenu">';
    $html .= '  <ul id="slidemenu" class="clearfix">';

    static $linkClass = 1;

    foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {                
        $html .= '<li class="themastyle' . $linkClass . '">' . l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link) . '</li>';
        ++$linkClass;
    }

    $html .= '  </ul>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
}
```

Not entirely sure if this is correct Drupal, though it did solve my issue!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Which version of Drupal?  You can tag your question "6" for Drupal 6 or "7" for Drupal 7.  Also, it may help if you could link to the answers you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Most of the other questions I've seen were about adding IDs and classes to list items of menus (http://drupal.org/node/1201248). Though it would seem the main menu and block menus are largely separate affairs. I've managed to add classes to block menus with theme_menu_link, though they don't apply to the main menu

Comment: Your solution after the edit is not a correct Drupal solution. You should rather look at this answer with some links to other solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5200802/517705. By the way, if you think you solved your own question, you should create a separate answer, and accept your own's! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r($main_menu);` each `$main_menu` items should have this structure:

```
array(
    'title' => 'xxx',
    'href' => 'xxx',
    'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('xxx'),
    ),
);
```

so you can add class to li by altering `$main_menu` array.

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. Could someone elaborate on how to edit $main_menu ?

Comment: in your question you mention `main menu is rendered like ...`, before this line of code you can modify your $main_menu array.

Answer (score 3):

[Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) is another great module that allows you to set `class`, `id`, `rel` and other attributes on either the `a` or `li` element.

Comment: Yes, in my experience Menu Attributes is the best choice for most projects. And I'm surprised this answer doesn't have more upvotes, with almost 6k views on this question.

Answer (score 1):

if your looking for a D8+ fix, the [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module saves a lot of time. You can specify attributes and classes through a YML file or directly to individual links in Admin Menu UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a existing module, you could also use [Menu Names CSS](http://drupal.org/project/menu_css_names). This module adds the target path of a menu item as a sanitized css-class to the li-item.

A second benefit is, that the module is good template how to put your functionality in a module instead of the template.php file, to increase the re-useability of your code.